# Ember.Select in emblemjs

Tags: ember.js, emblem.js

I am trying to use `Ember.Select` in my template. `Ember.Select` works without any attribute | properties. But when I specify a attribute content, it gives me error as

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed countries
```

My emblem template is as follows,

```
Ember.Select     // Works fine
Ember.Select content=countries //Gives the listed error
```

The code in App.IndexController is,

```
countries : function () {
    return ["India","US","England"]; // I have also tried passing the value in Ember.A(array_val)
}.property('')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Emblem but first off, it's probably worth trying to create a select as per the [API documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html) and defining `countries` as a literal array.

```
countries : ["India","US","England"],
```

However I think that your problem is that you are defining it as a `.property('')` called nothing. If you don't want to rename your property, just set it like this: `.property()`, or if you want to call it something different `.property('countriesCollection')`. This would then allow you to use `countriesCollection` in your templates.

You should also have a look into [computed properties](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/object-model/computed-properties/), as presumably you want to do something to your array (otherwise it might as well be a literal array).

On another note, Ember 1.13 has [deprecated](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view) views, so you should actually look to move to a component driven approach, instead of using views and controllers. There is a good `select` component called [x-select](https://github.com/thefrontside/emberx-select) which is compatible with the Ember.Select view API.